# Real time audio streaming

Tags: networking, audio, streaming, vlc-media-player, remote-access

I have a remote computer running OS X. I would like to stream the audio from the microphone input over the network so I can listen to it. Primarily I want to do this because I'm out of the office but still need to communicate with people there.

I would like to use VLC, but am not fully aware of the options available. I tried SoundFly (as recommended by another answer) but this didn't seem to want to connect. At this point I should note that I'm using a VPN network to connect to the remote computer (using Hamachi). I can open up ports / etc fine though, so I *should* be able to do this.

Alright, I found [Nicecase](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/nicecast/) which does *exactly what I want* but I would prefer to not have to shell out $40 for it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not going to be able to do this with VLC.  According to the [VLC Features page](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html) VLC on the Mac only supports video capture (see [footnote #5](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html#input_notes)).